# How can we (or might we) achieve presentational sound effects via CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, presentation

If we start by accepting that:

- HTML is for **structure**
- CSS is for **presentation**
- JS is for **behaviour**

> **N.B.** We can debate whether *presentation which responds to user
> interaction* is simply another way to say *behaviour*. That's certainly one view.
>
> However, the vast array of interactive visual effects around the web declared
> entirely in CSS and initiated by `:hover` and `:focus` and
> `:focus-within` etc. pseudo-class states suggests another view is widely
> shared that CSS is a legitimate technology for handling what we might
> call *interactive presentation*.

I want to ask (because I can find nothing) if, for all the many and varied ways CSS is deployed to handle **interactive visual presentation** it is ever deployed to handle ***interactive aural presentation***?

1. Have there been attempts to introduce **aural presentation** to CSS?
2. Is there a proposal to introduce **aural presentation** to CSS?

Is there any sort of official approach at all (even if never or not yet implemented by browsers) to achieve what the following demo does, using the following (made-up) CSS properties:

- `audio`
- `audio-duration`
- `audio-play`

---

**Working Example:**

Please humour me and pretend that the hastily written javascript below isn't there and that it's as if CSS styles like:

```
.square:unhover {
  audio: url(//cdn.freesound.org/previews/628/628357_1486333-lq.mp3);
  audio-duration: 1.776s;
  audio-play: 2;
}
```

just work, as-is.

```js
// BUILD STYLESHEET ARRAY
const stylesheet = document.head.querySelector('style');
let stylesheetText = stylesheet.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '');
let stylesheetArray = stylesheetText.split('}');
stylesheetArray.pop();

// BUILD SELECTORS ARRAY
let selectorsArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < stylesheetArray.length; i++) {
  selectorsArray[i] = {
    selector: stylesheetArray[i].split('{')[0],
    styles: {}
  };
  
  let selectorRules = stylesheetArray[i].split('{')[1].split(';')
  selectorRules.pop();
  
  for (let j = 0; j < selectorRules.length; j++) {
  
    selectorsArray[i].styles[selectorRules[j].split(':')[0]] = selectorRules[j].split(':')[1];
  }
}

// BUILD TARGET QUERIES ARRAY
let targetQueriesArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < selectorsArray.length; i++) {
  
  if ((/:hover|:unhover/).test(selectorsArray[i].selector)) {
  
    if (Object.keys(selectorsArray[i].styles).includes('audio')) {
  
      let targetQuery = selectorsArray[i];
      
      switch (true) {
    
        case (targetQuery.selector.includes(':hover')): targetQuery.event = 'mouseover'; break;
        case (targetQuery.selector.includes(':unhover')): targetQuery.event = 'mouseout'; break;
      }
    
      targetQueriesArray.push(targetQuery);
    }
  }
}

// DECLARE playAudioViaCSS FUNCTION
const playAudioViaCSS = (audioURL, audioDuration, audioPlays) => {

  let soundEffectViaCSS = new Audio(audioURL);
  soundEffectViaCSS.loop = true;
  soundEffectViaCSS.play();
  
  setTimeout(() => soundEffectViaCSS.loop = false, (audioDuration * audioPlays));
}

// ATTACH AUDIO EVENTS TO TARGET ELEMENTS
for (let i = 0; i < targetQueriesArray.length; i++) {
 
  let targetAudio = targetQueriesArray[i].styles.audio.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
  let targetAudioDuration = (targetQueriesArray[i].styles['audio-duration'].replace('s', '') * 1000) || 1000;
  let targetAudioPlays = targetQueriesArray[i].styles['audio-play'] || 1;
  let targetEvent = targetQueriesArray[i].event;
  let targetQuery = targetQueriesArray[i].selector.replace(/:hover|:unhover/g, '');

  let targetElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(targetQuery)];
  targetElements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener(targetEvent, () => playAudioViaCSS(targetAudio, targetAudioDuration, targetAudioPlays), false));
};
```

```css
:root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.9s ease-out; 
}

.square:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  audio: url(//cdn.freesound.org/previews/354/354062_1490240-lq.mp3);
  audio-duration: 2.304s;
  audio-play: 3;
}

.square:unhover {
  audio: url(//cdn.freesound.org/previews/628/628357_1486333-lq.mp3);
  audio-duration: 1.776s;
  audio-play: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
Hover me
</div>
```

Comment: Answer is no...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Speech/NOTE-ACSS-961210

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aural

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, @epascarello. I did spend some time hunting for blog posts on Smashing Magazine, AListApart, SitePoint, CSS-Tricks etc. but I was just drawing blanks. If you want to post those two links below within an answer, I will be delighted to accept. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, besides a simple "no" I would ask back about your question: I don't know (I really don't...) if there really is some kind of definition somewhere that CSS is for presentation, and if there is, if that isn't meant as "visual presentation". The way I learned it is rather that CSS is for *layout* (which basically *is*  visual presentation). Concerning audio on websites, the simplest thing that comes to mind is the `<audio>` tag, which belongs to the `HTML` part of the code...

Comment: @Johannes - I think - if I recall correctly - that _"HTML is for content, CSS is for layout"_ was the precursor to _"HTML is for structure, CSS is for presentation, JS is for behaviour"_. Good point about the HTML5 `<audio>` element.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine The way audio appears in your example, it would be kind of "background-audio" (like a background-image opposed to a regular image element), so that indeed would be "aural presentation", but rather of an action (= behaviour, i.e. hover, click and similar) than of an HTML element.

Comment: Yes, `background-image` was precisely my inspiration for this. Thanks for recognising exactly what I was going for. :-D

Answer (score 1):

CSS handles the look and feel part of a web page. Using CSS, you can control the color of the text, the style of fonts, the spacing between paragraphs, how columns are sized and laid out, etc. CSS saves time − You can write CSS once and then reuse the same sheet in multiple HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks, @Avihaa - see my question about ***aural** presentation* vs. *visual presentation*.